# HttpUrlConnection not working with setRequestProperty

Tags: java, soap, httpurlconnection

Does somebody have an explanation to what is going on?

The code snippet below shows how I am preparing the connection.

The problem is:

When
`connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");`
Is added, I am getting a `400 Bad request`, but if I remove the line, it works.

```
@Override
protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection)
        throws IOException {
    String userPassword = taskProperties.getCadyUser() + ":" + taskProperties.getCadyPass();
    String encodedAuthorization = new String(Base64.encode(userPassword.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");
    super.prepareConnection(connection);
}
```

Working example:

```
    @Override
    protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection)
            throws IOException {
        String userPassword = taskProperties.getCadyUser() + ":" + taskProperties.getCadyPass();
        String encodedAuthorization = new String(Base64.encode(userPassword.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedAuthorization);
        super.prepareConnection(connection);
    }
```

Does anyone have an explanation to this phenomena?

Comment: Maybe the server doesn't support text/xml or UTF-8? Or you don't send the content as UTF-8?

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the case. I managed to figure out what was wrong and why it behaves as it did. But thank you for the answer.